# Replacing Windows 7 with Windows 8 while on dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, windows-8

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 64b alongside . I just want now to remove "7" and install
 Windows 8.1 .
Should I just insert Windows 8.1 CD and start installation as I would do on "normal" ,non dual boot systems?
Is that possible without corrupting and/or doing anything with Ubuntu partition because in the past I installed Ubuntu after Windows 7?
Is the order of installing important and what are the main differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the specific instructions totally depend on your situation, partitioning etc. You should insert Windows 8 disc and replace Windows 7 (if you want that removed of course), simply format Windows 7 partition and install Windows 8.
After doing so, your GRUB bootloader will be inaccessible, you should insert and boot an Ubuntu LiveCD and fix GRUB (using commands or GUI tools like [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)).

Comment: Is LiveCD the only option or I can do it with bootable USB too?

Comment: @holyreality there is no difference between Live CD and Live USB.

Comment: @holyreality Yes you can, these terms are used interchangeably recently :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few details missing in your question like the partition layout and firmware type of your computer (BIOS or UEFI). Usually Windows 7 installations are BIOS/MBR, which means the Ubuntu bootloader (GRUB) would be overwritten with every operating system you are going install, it doesn't matter if its Windows 7, Windows 8 or something else and you would need to reinstall GRUB to restore dual boot functionality: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/40581)

> Newer systems with properly working UEFI don't have this limitation of a single bootloader per disk, but a lot of UEFI systems sold up until now are designed as Windows only booting devices. An invasive design decision that wasn't anyhow required by Microsoft for traditional computers, but forced onto users by probably the same guys who'd thought that Superfish-like malware would add value to the user experience and a connection made to your bank or any other critical site with this thing sniffing all the traffic would still be secure. (It's not.) That's why there is much uncertainty with Windows 8 and Linux, thought there's nothing wrong with both of them.

Comment: Thanks for additional info about UEFI . Does "designed as Windows only booting devices" means they actually forced people to use Windows only on devices they actually gave money for? And that action was not even required by Microsoft? This all sounds like dictatorship in IT world,something Microsoft practiced back in the days.